# ternary conditional operator equivalent?

Tags: c, ternary-operator

I'm trying to understand a while loop. I realize the basics of how ternary operators work, but have only used them in loo of if statements, not in a while loop.This piece of code is really throwing me off. What would be the equivalent to this statement if it was not shortened?

```
int runOnce=0;
while(runOnce=runOnce?((token=strtok(NULL," "))!=NULL):((token=strtok(strCopy," "))!=NULL)) {
    ....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, let's go over it one by one. As you said you know the the basics to ternary operator, so I will get right to the problem. The code here :

```
// notice here I did not include the the assignment(=) operation and the variable before it
runOnce?((token=strtok(NULL," "))!=NULL):((token=strtok(strCopy," "))!=NULL)
```

which basically means

```
if(runOnce)
{
    return ((token=strtok(NULL," "))!=NULL);
}
else
{
    return ((token=strtok(strCopy," "))!=NULL);
}
```

This return value in turn will be save to the same variable *runOnce*

```
runOnce = // ternary condition mentioned above
```

So, finally if the variable *runOnce* is true, then the condition for while loop will be true

**Updated:** 
To make the code more understandable you can do something like this

```
int runOnce=0;
while(conditionForWhileLoop(runOnce)) 
{
    // ...
}

int conditionForWhileLoop(int runOnce)
{
    if(runOnce)
    {
        return ((token=strtok(NULL," "))!=NULL);
    }
    else
    {
        return ((token=strtok(strCopy," "))!=NULL);
    }
}
```

Of course there is a lot you can do than this, but it's a start

Comment: Okay that clears it up a bit. But would I be able to write it that way too using a while loop? Rather using the ternary operator while loop statement in one of my programs, I would like to implement it in an easier to read kind of way.

Comment: "I be able to write it that way too using a while loop?" - I did not understand this part, but what I gather is that you want to write the condition in such a way that it will be easier to read, is that correct? Are you trying to avoid using ternary operator?

Comment: Yes sorry about my English. Yup, I'm trying to remove the use of a ternary operator.

Comment: I have updated the answer, let me know what you think

Comment: yes that's more of what I was looking for. I'll test it out and get back to ya. Thanks friend

Comment: @FatFockFrank if the answer helped, it would be nice if you would accept the answer :)

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit clearer in my opinion.

```
token = strtok (strCopy," ");
while (token!=NULL)
{
    /* do stuff */
    token = strtok (NULL," ");
}
```